# When is Nesting OK in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Firebase's [Structuring Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) documentation explicitly says to "Avoid Building Nests". The primary reason given is that

> when we fetch data for a node in Firebase, we also retrieve all of its child nodes.

With this in mind, is it still efficient to nest deeply if the data is still denormalized properly?

For example, here is a possible Firebase structure for an app with geotagged posts and [geo-indexes](https://github.com/firebase/geofire/) by post language:

```
posts/{postId}
indexes/
        languages/
                  en/geohashes/{geohash}
                  es/geohashes/{geohash}
                  de/geohashes/{geohash}
```

Compare this to a completely flat structure:

```
posts/{postId}
index_en_geohashes/{geohash}
index_es_geohashes/{geohash}
index_de_geohashes/{geohash}
```

I find the first nested structure clean and self-documenting. Is this just as efficient as the flat structure? (Let's say the most common use-case is 'query language x geohashes')

Comment: "is it still acceptable" is often highly subjective. But the question you need to always answer with Firebase data structuring is simple: will I regularly need the geohashes of all languages in my application? If not, I would typically store then in a flat structure. But as I said: that is subjective, so anyone is free to disagree.

Comment: very fair - "acceptable" is indeed subjective :) I removed it. But are the two structures equally efficient in the simple use case of 'get all geohashes for German posts'?

Comment: In the case of "get all german posts", they are equivalent. Where they fall down is when you start iterating and filtering data. This depends entirely on how you will read the data and, based on what you've shared thus far, a nested structure seems valid.

Comment: I think the confusion is because nesting is relative from the point of view. If you're accessing `indexes/languages/en/geohashes`, you're not reading a nested structure. If you're accessing `index_en_geohashes/` you're not reading a nested structure. When you start accessing `indexes/languages/`, then you're accessing a nested structure and likely reading more data than you need. That's really what the idea of "avoid building nests" is about.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This makes complete sense. I understand that a query of `indexes/languages/` would return all child data. There still isn't a way to just fetch child keys, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query from the nested structure `/indexes/languages/en/geohashes/` and flat structure `/index_en_geohashes/` are computationally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks to Kato and Leeft for their help with this question.